# How to make changes to files inside /odoo/src and commit and merge with production branch?

Tags: odoo, odoo-13

I am running `Odoo 13`. I created a new staging branch and used the Odoo.sh web editor to make changes to `primary_variables.scss` (`/src/odoo/addons/web/static/src/scss/primary_variables.scss`). However I can't figure out how to commit these changes and push them to my staging branch and merge with the production branch. If I navigate to `/src/user` and `git branch -r` I can see all my `staging` branches however if I navigate to `/src/odoo` and run `git branch -r` I can see two branches `origin/HEAD` and `origin/13.0`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do that.

Your instance is made up of 4 git repositories. `/src/odoo` is from https://github.com/odoo/odoo You can change only `/src/user`

You have to write your own module. That overwrites some CSS values or replaces it fully.

The next link speaks how to load your CSS file. I think you can load your modified file. As it is loaded later the original then it should overwrite original CSS.

https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/reference/javascript_reference.html#assets-management